# How to limit width of <h1> - <h5> tag by length of content

Tags: css, html

Thanks for taking your time for my question. 
I know, this question has been asked and answered before, but somehow i can't make it look like expected. I will show you below some of the things I've tried.

I have a div with a rounded boarder where i want to display a caption (one of the standard captions  - ).

This is what i've got:

HTML:

```
<div id="selectModel" class="admin_dropdown">
   <h5 class="admin_caption">Wählen sie das anzuzeigende Model</h5>
   [...]
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h5.admin_caption {

        width: 300px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background: white;

    }
```

I am not allowed to post pictures (<10 rep), so I hope jsfiddle works).

How it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/vrP39/

What i want it to look like: http://jsfiddle.net/vrP39/1/

As you can see, the result of the last fiddle is achieved through changing the `width` until it matches the caption. Of course i want to use it with several captions with different length, so this is not an option.

What i've tried so far:

1. Using a `<span>` around the text in my caption, also styling the `<span>` element instead of the `<h5>`
2. `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`
3. `float: left` in the `<h5>` and `clear:left` in the following element

I saw this post (amongst others) here on stackoverflow ([Width of Headers (H1, H2 etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160759/width-of-headers-h1-h2-etc)) but nothing that i tried seems to work.

What did i do wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: So you just want to `center` the caption text, regardless of the width?

Comment: @NickR, The problem with that solution is the background of the text has to be `white` to cover the line, but only the bit that the text covers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to reproduce a [`<fieldset>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_fieldset.asp) element. So why not use that element?

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Wählen sie das anzuzeigende Model</legend>
        <select id="selectModelDDL" onchange="createTable(this);">
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

With the `<fieldset>` you will create the border around the elements where the `<legend>` is the text that is on the border.
Now you can just align the text to the center:

```
fieldset
{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrP39/3/)

Comment: Thanks! Looks exactly what i tried to build after adding `width: 300px` in CSS :)

Answer (score 2):

Working with your current code, you can do this : http://jsfiddle.net/vrP39/6/

Add a `<span>` inside the `h5` (for the background colour)

`<h5 class="admin_caption"><span>Wählen sie das anzuzeigende Model</span></h5>`

And for the `CSS`

```
h5.admin_caption { text-align:center; margin-top: -20px; }
h5.admin_caption span { display:inline-block; background:#fff; padding:0 5px;}
```

The first bit centres the text, and then we have to add in a background to hide the black border line.

The `span` needs to be set to `inline-block`, so we can add a bit of padding on the left and right, as you can't do that if the `span>` element is using the default `display:inline` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to wrap the caption in a div:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="selectModel" class="admin_dropdown">
        <div class="caption_wrapper">
             <h5 class="admin_caption">Wählen sie das anzuzeigende Model</h5>
        </div>
        <select id="selectModelDDL" onchange="createTable(this);"></select>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.caption_wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 1px;
}
h5.admin_caption {
    background: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/vrP39/9/**

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/33c4N/

```
 max-width: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
```

I've given a max-width and hidden the overflow to get the desired effect.

Comment: I like the `fieldset` solution better, but this also works. Thanks for your help!